# Firefox calls <base> url

Tags: jsp, firefox, gwt, radix

On a customer's site somebody in ancient times put a `<base>`-tag in a super-parent tile definition that is just plain weird. It's just referring to itself, lets say its `basicTileLayout.jsp` that's putting out a tag:

```
<base href="http://site.com/layout/basicTileLayout.jsp" />
```

in the head.

The site is nowadays mostly GWT. Anyway, for some weird reason Firefox and only Firefox sometimes makes an ajax call to this base-URL when for example clicking a GWT-generated link looking like this in the DOM:

```
<a class="gwt-Anchor" href="javascript:;">Read more</a>
```

My first idea was that it probably was some event-bubbling that worked differently in FF and that there maybe was some href="" that got called while prevented by the GWT event handling in other browsers. But then, removing the base-tag should probably have yielded a GET to the apps base context path instead ("/"), right? This doesn't happen. So it seems the existence of this base-tag triggers FF to make the call.

The reason I'm asking is that this is a super-global chrome-tile so removing the base tag would change EVERY relative href on the whole site. I'm tempted to do it, but just a tiny bit scared :)

**Update:**

I did some GWT-googling and found this IE-related thingy:

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5280

I went through the code and noticed that it seems to happen on just links generated using GWT:s Anchor and without calling preventDefault on the event from the event-handler.

A guess could then be that Firefox maybe does this GET to the base-url on the unloadEvent that gets called since we don't prevent the default. But why there's an ajax call to the url only if the base-tag i present I cannot understand.

**Update 2:**

I tried calling preventDefault on the click event but this doesn't help. If there is a base-tag present, FF get that url and if its not there nothing bad happens.

Any pointers highly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this was caused by empty img-tags:

```
<img src="" class="gwt-Image">
```

So apparently, if there is a `<base>` in head, Firefox will actually just use it concatenated with this empty src-attribute and therefore make a GET to the url in base. No webkit-browser, nor IE does it.

This is probably the correct thing to do. I'll reference the issue I read about over at FF:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=444931

Comment: Note that if you think about this *logically*, this makes perfect sense.  You provided a source URL, it got resolved as normal against the base, and so the current page got loaded again.  That's not to say the specs say it should work like this (I came here via your comment in the bug).  I don't know what they say.  (And whatever they say could possibly be changed, with great enough justification.)  But it is to note that not loading the URL again would be a special case, if it's what's called for.

Comment: @Jeff - Sure! However, I'm not really sure if there was a call against the default base if there was not base-tag present - but I didn't notice it. That was confusing to me - that there was a call against the url in the base-tag but not against the default one. I mighe be wrong though and gonna have too check again.